# Is there a ship with the serial number "NCC-4701D"?

Tags: star-trek, uss-enterprise

In the *Star Trek* TV shows and movies, has the *Enterprise* or any other ship ever had the serial number "NCC-4701D"?

Comment: Just curious, why that serial specifically? Its similar to the Enterprises NCC-1701. Does 4701 have any meaning?

Comment: I won't downvote this question because there's technically nothing wrong with it, but I almost did anyways because it is so oddly specific and you could have looked it up anytime on google if you want to. Not that you would have found the specific registry you asked about.

Answer (score 7):

Searching for "NCC-4701D" does not bring up any results. I have no reason to believe that a ship with this serial number exists in the *Star Trek* universe.

You are almost certainly thinking of [NCC-**1**701-D](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USS_Enterprise_(NCC-1701-D)), which was the serial number of the *Enterprise* as it appeared in *Star Trek: The Next Generation* and the film *Star Trek: Generations*.

Comment: +1 *And* NCC-1701-D appeared in the third season of *ST:Picard*.